# scp connection refused error

Tags: ssh

I am trying to transfer a file from linux server to macosx machine using `scp`.

`scp test username@68.120.23.91:~/`

it shows error

`ssh: connect to host 68.120.23.91 port 22: Connection refused
  lost connection.`

I checked firewall settings on mac it allows all connections from all machine.
Please help me asap.

Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Is sshd up and running?

Comment: Have you tried ssh -vvv test username@68.120.23.91:~/ ?  This will give you more info on the error.

Answer (score 6):

Connection refused, if not the firewall, often indicates that the ssh service is not running on the remote computer.

Running

```
ps -aux | grep sshd
```

on the remote computer will verify if it's running or not - IF you can somehow access that remote box.

Comment: yes, `sudo apt install openssh-server` immediately solved the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: I wish I could upvote Yan's response, that was the answer in my case as well.

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac, go to System Preferences > Sharing and make sure Remote Login is enabled (checked).

Also, shouldn't you have escaped the `~` in that `scp` command? Otherwise I'm afraid your local (Linux) shell will swallow it and replace it with the path to your Linux account's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing openssh-client and openssh-server on your target computer if Linux. Otherwise the suitable ssh server for your Operating System.

Answer (score 0):

If your `ssh` connection uses a specific port, set it for `scp` as well with

```
scp -P 1234 <other params>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are logged in as root which is often needed to reach a protected folder on the server. User root is not allowed in scp.

```
root@123.456.789.123's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Instead, on the server and logged in as root, copy the file to an unprotected folder like /tmp. Then exit the root user or scp from outside and use scp with a normal user, not root.

Then you avoid:

```bash
Connection refused 
lost connection
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you use the right IP, the one from the remote.

I made the mistake to copy and paste the wrong IP, name wlp0s20f3, from the wrong list of IPs, a list that I had taken from my own machine, using `ip a`, although I should have taken the other output list of the remote machine instead. Since I mixed this up, I took an IP that simply did not allow me to enter, and it would not have helped anyway since it was from the same machine.